# Shader - Unexpected behaviour when dividing with a high value

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I have this line:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(worldPos.x / maxX, worldPos.z / maxZ, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Where worldPos.x and worldPos.y goes from 0 to 19900. maxX and maxZ are float uniforms. It works as expected when maxX and maxZ are set to 5000.0 (a gradient to white and above 5000 it's all white), but when maxX and maxZ are set to 19900.0 it all turns blue. Why is that and how to get around it? Hardcoding the values doesn't make a difference, i.e:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(worldPos.x / 5000.0, worldPos.z / 5000.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

works as expected while:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(worldPos.x / 19900.0, worldPos.z / 19900.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

makes it all blue. This only happens on some devices and not on others.

**Update:**

Adding highp modifier (as suggested by Michael below) solved it for one device, but when testing on another it didn't make any difference. Then I tried to do the division on the CPU (also suggested by Michael) like this:

in java, before passing it as uniform:

```
float maxX = 1.0f / 19900.0f;
float maxZ = 1.0f / 19900.0f;
program.setUniformf(maxXUniform, maxX);
program.setUniformf(maxZUniform, maxZ);
```

in shader:

```
uniform float maxX;
uniform float maxZ;

...
gl_FragColor = vec4(worldPos.x * maxX, worldPos.z * maxZ, 1.0, 1.0);
...
```

**Final sulotion:**

This still didn't cut it. Now the values are too small so when passed in to the shader they turn 0 due to too low float precision. Then I tried to multiply it by 100 before passing it in, and then multiplying it by 0.01 inside the shader.

in java:

```
float maxX = 100.0f / 19900.0f;
float maxZ = 100.0f / 19900.0f;
program.setUniformf(maxXUniform, maxX);
program.setUniformf(maxZUniform, maxZ);
```

in shader:

```
uniform float maxX;
uniform float maxZ;

...
gl_FragColor = vec4(worldPos.x * 0.01 * maxX, worldPos.z * 0.01 * maxZ, 1.0, 1.0);
...
```

And that solved the problem. Now the highp modifier isn't needed. Maybe it isn't the prettiest sulotion but it's efficient and robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're running OpenGL ES? Well,the floating precision sucks on many,usually quite old, devices.I had similar issues on several occasions when implementing cascaded shadows mapping in shaders for mobile hardware.

Make sure you use `highp` qualifier for those variables. (note - that might not solve the issue, but is worth to try)

Another possible solution: don't perform the division in the shader. That's a quite heavy operation for many old and weak implementations anyway. Try to avoid division, sqrt(),pow().Run shader profiler and you will be surprised to find out how much those ops are HEAVY! (iOS emulator on Mac has a nice shader profiler) Try to pass the results directly as uniforms.I am not sure that would be a problem in your case,as I can't see any of these variables bound to per-fragment execution.

And if it still doesn't help, then usually there is nothing you can do about that. That's the old hardware/GLSL implementation issue. But I am sure,if you calculate that on CPU and upload the results as uniforms, that should solve the issue.

Comment: Yea, that's right, it's a fairly old Android (xperia z3 compact) and OpenGL ES. I guess by deletion you mean division? I'll give it a try to pass in the result of 1.0 / 19900.0 to the uniform and multiply by that value instead. I'll get back here when it's done.

Comment: @Johan right, was my typo. I mean - division. Try to perform it on CPU.It is also right thing to do performance wise.Just think about that - you perform the division PER FRAGMENT!

Comment: Can you store a per-vertex color value and use interpolation instead?

Comment: Adding the highp modifier did the job, thanks for that! 

Remarks: Doing the division on the GPU or CPU didn't make any difference, it still became 0 in the shader. Calculating the color per vertex is'nt really an option (the posted code was only for troubleshooting). The calculations are done for normal mapping so I needed to calculate it based on the world position which is calculated in the vertex shader, hence I can't precalculate it before I know the position.

Comment: @Johan happy to hear it solved for you with highp. I had much worse experience with old devices,where precision qualifiers did no difference.

Comment: Turns out adding highp wasn't enough after all, I updated the question with my final sulotion.